# java Collections Interview questions on comon methods

Tags: collections, frameworks

In Capgemini interview I was asked one question i could not answer. What are those methods which are common to all the collection classes and interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

All java object classes (which include all the collections) are derived from the base class called [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). This class has some methods which are available to all objects (because they are sub-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the methods like **add(), addAll(), clear(), iterator()** are the methods which are common to all collection classes and interface.